# PHP not loading full image on first load, but loading full image on subsequent loads till refresh

Tags: php, html, image

I am working on a gallery page that uses PHP to load images outside web root, on my initial webpage I have thumbnails sitting within an anchor tag that that looks like this for calling the medium sized image onclick

```
    href="/view_file.php?file=115&medium=1&v=239"
```

and this calls this bit of code from the view_file page

```
        case "jpg":
            header('Content-length: ' . $fsize);
            header('Cache-control: private');
            header('Content-type: ' . $fmime . '; name="' . $nameOrig . '.' . $fext . '"');
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $nameOrig . '.' . $fext . '"');
            $modified=filemtime($fullPath);
            header('Last-Modified: '. date('D, j M Y G:i:s T',$modified));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            @readfile($fullPath);
            exit;
```

This bit of code is also used to display the thumbnails on the original page. However when loading the medium sized images, it only loads about the first 5% or so of the image before stopping. If i go back and click on the same image again, i am presented with the full sized medium image. If i refresh the thumbnail page i once again run into the same issue. 
Full view file page in the pastebin linked below
http://pastebin.com/vhd46Pdw

EDIT
after tinkering around a bit, i found that the $fsize variable is being set incorrectly on the first load, however upon page refresh it is loaded with the correct variable

Comment: are you sure $fsize is correct each time? Also, why are you copying the file to a temporary location if you are then just outputting the contents directly?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I see two other problems. (1) Redirects don't end the script. You need a `die();` or `exit();` after a `header('Location: ...');` otherwise it will continue executing the rest of the page. (2) Blatant SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Anthony i use `$fsize = filesize($fullPath);` to initialize `$fsize` and i believe i was told the temporary location was for download purposes if im not mistaken